# Issues with minimum size and alignment of image objects in Qt rich text

Tags: qt, pyqt, qlabel

I would like to create a small, basic persistent QLabel for a QStatusBar, which also has a small icon based on the font height. The icon is actually a `base64` embedded `<img>`, so that I can use the common Qt rich text engine of QLabel instead of creating a composite widget.

The image size is based on the font metrics, so it should *technically* fit the minimum size hint of the label. If the font metrics returns a height of 16 pixels, adding an embedded image that has a 16 pixel height should *not* change the label hint. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem the case.

As soon as the image is added to the label, the height is increased even if the image height is equal to the font metrics' height, and it's always vertically aligned to the top; trying to set the alignment doesn't seem to help that much, which is probably related to [this qt-forum post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/92060/alignment-of-images-in-rich-text/2).

Using HTML tables partially solves the problem: the vertical alignment is respected, but the added margin is still present.

I know that we're just talking about a few pixels, but I really don't like the current behavior: switching between a text that *does* have an image and another that does *not*, results in changing the whole layout (and, possibly, the size hint of the parent widget, which clearly is a problem especially if the label has to be used in a QStatusBar).

While a possibility is to add a "ghost" image (`width=0`) whenever no image should be shown, I'm still interested in understanding why this is happening and *if* it can be overridden.

I know that there could be some sort of work around by accessing a QTextDocument's layout, but, since QLabel uses QTextDocument only privately, this is not a possible approach.

I also know that I could just ignore all that and create a QWidget subclass, properly override `sizeHint` and `paintEvent` and go along with all that, but that's not the point.

While the Qt rich text documentation implies that alignment properties are supported, the vertical alignment seems to be ignored in almost any case for images, except for `"middle"`, which actually aligns the image to the top of the (possibly) next line, and that's something that doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

To better understand the problem, here is a basic demo that shows my point.
The labels are layout-aligned and use a border, so you can clearly see the bounding rect of each item: whenever an image is added, some margin is added (the extent depends on the OS and style).
The code is based on PyQt, but I know that the issue is on the Qt side:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

StyleSheet = 'QLabel { border: 1px solid darkGray; }'
BaseText = '<img {align} src="data:image/png;base64,{img};"> {label}'
TableText = '<table><tr><td {align}><img src="data:image/png;base64,{img};"></td><td>{label}</td></tr></table>'

class LabelTest(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central)
        top = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(top)

        boldFont = self.font()
        boldFont.setBold(True)

        top.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Icon theme:'))
        self.iconCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        top.addWidget(self.iconCombo)
        currentTheme = QtGui.QIcon.themeName().lower()
        themes = []
        for iconPath in QtGui.QIcon.themeSearchPaths():
            it = QtCore.QDirIterator(iconPath, ['*'], QtCore.QDir.Dirs|QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)
            while it.hasNext():
                if QtCore.QDir(it.next()).exists('index.theme'):
                    themeName = it.fileName()
                    if themeName.lower() in themes:
                        continue
                    themes.append(themeName.lower())
                    if themeName.lower() == currentTheme:
                        index = self.iconCombo.count()
                        self.iconCombo.addItem(themeName + '*', themeName)
                        self.iconCombo.model().setData(
                            self.iconCombo.model().index(index, 0), 
                                boldFont, QtCore.Qt.FontRole)
                        self.iconCombo.setCurrentIndex(index)
                    else:
                        self.iconCombo.addItem(themeName, themeName)

        top.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Style'))
        self.styleCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        top.addWidget(self.styleCombo)
        currentStyle = self.style().objectName().lower()
        for i, styleName in enumerate(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys()):
            if styleName.lower() == currentStyle:
                # automatically select the current style
                self.styleCombo.addItem(styleName + '*', styleName)
                self.styleCombo.model().setData(
                    self.styleCombo.model().index(i, 0), 
                    boldFont, QtCore.Qt.FontRole)
                self.styleCombo.setCurrentIndex(i)
            else:
                self.styleCombo.addItem(styleName, styleName)

        self.boundingRectCheck = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Bounding rect')
        top.addWidget(self.boundingRectCheck)
        top.addStretch()

        mid = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(mid)
        self.alignCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        mid.addWidget(self.alignCombo)
        for alignment in ('', 'top', 'super', 'middle', 'baseline', 'sub', 'bottom'):
            if alignment:
                self.alignCombo.addItem(alignment.title(), alignment)
            else:
                self.alignCombo.addItem('No alignment')
        self.tableCheck = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Table')
        mid.addWidget(self.tableCheck)
        self.labelIconCheck = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Status icon')
        mid.addWidget(self.labelIconCheck)
        self.statusCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        mid.addWidget(self.statusCombo)

        frameLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        layout.addLayout(frameLayout)
        frameLayout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
        self.labelData = []
        for label in ('Information', 'Warning', 'Critical', 'Question'):
            row = frameLayout.rowCount()
            self.statusCombo.addItem(label)
            pixmapLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(styleSheet=StyleSheet)
            frameLayout.addWidget(pixmapLabel, 
                row, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            frameLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(label, styleSheet=StyleSheet), 
                row, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
            formattedLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(styleSheet=StyleSheet)
            frameLayout.addWidget(formattedLabel, 
                row, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
            self.labelData.append((label, pixmapLabel, formattedLabel))

        mid.addStretch()

        self.editor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
        self.editor.setMinimumHeight(1)
        frameLayout.addWidget(self.editor, 1, 3, frameLayout.rowCount(), 1)

        self.statusLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(styleSheet=StyleSheet)
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.statusLabel)

        self.iconCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.setStatus)
        self.styleCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateStyle)
        self.alignCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.setStatus)
        self.boundingRectCheck.toggled.connect(self.setStatus)
        self.tableCheck.toggled.connect(self.setStatus)
        self.statusCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.setStatus)
        self.labelIconCheck.toggled.connect(self.setStatus)

        self.setStatus()

    def setStatus(self):
        self.editor.clear()
        align = self.alignCombo.currentData()
        if self.tableCheck.isChecked():
            baseText = TableText
            if align:
                align = 'style="vertical-align: {}"'.format(align)
        else:
            baseText = BaseText
            if align:
                align = 'align="{}"'.format(align)

        statusIcon = self.labelIconCheck.isChecked()
        if not statusIcon:
            self.statusLabel.setText(self.statusCombo.currentText())
        boundingRect = self.boundingRectCheck.isChecked()
        
        pen1 = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black)
        pen1.setDashPattern([1, 1])
        pen2 = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white)
        pen2.setDashPattern([1, 1])
        pen2.setDashOffset(1)

        # create pixmaps from the icon theme, with size based on the font metrics
        QtGui.QIcon.setThemeName(self.iconCombo.currentData())
        iconSize = self.fontMetrics().height()
        for i, (label, pixmapLabel, formattedLabel) in enumerate(self.labelData):
            enum = getattr(QtWidgets.QStyle, 'SP_MessageBox' + label)
            icon = self.style().standardIcon(enum)
            pixmap = icon.pixmap(iconSize)
            pixmapLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)

            if boundingRect and not pixmap.isNull():
                qp = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
                qp.setPen(pen1)
                qp.drawRect(pixmap.rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))
                qp.setPen(pen2)
                qp.drawRect(pixmap.rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))
                qp.end()

            # create a QByteArray of the resized icon so that we can use the
            # embedded base64 data for the HTML image
            byteArray = QtCore.QByteArray()
            buffer = QtCore.QBuffer(byteArray)
            buffer.open(buffer.WriteOnly)
            pixmap.save(buffer, 'png')
            imageData = byteArray.toBase64().data().decode()
            embedText = baseText.format(
                img=imageData, 
                label=label, 
                align=align
            )
            formattedLabel.setText(embedText)
            if statusIcon:
                if i == self.statusCombo.currentIndex():
                    self.statusLabel.setText(formattedLabel.text())
                self.editor.append(embedText)
            else:
                self.editor.append(label)

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(50, lambda: self.resize(self.minimumSizeHint()))

    def updateStyle(self):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle(self.styleCombo.currentData())
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(50, lambda: self.resize(self.minimumSizeHint()))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = LabelTest()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

This is what the above code basically shows:

[image: result of the above code]

Comment: For me, Top alignment works perfectly - which is to say, the height of the right label is exactly the same as the left label (and the height of the status-bar label doesn't change). That would seem to make sense, given [how vertical-align is defined for CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) - i.e. if the image-height is the same as the line-height, aligning their top edges should make them overlap exactly. Middle alignment looks quite tricky, given that it is based on the x-height.

Comment: PS: one thing that isn't totally clear from your screenshot is the form of the icons. Are the visible pixels centrally aligned, and do they fill the entire area of the image?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for your input! I improved the test code (see the update) to show the image extent and in the meantime I had the opportunity to do further testing. Turns out that with a newer Qt version and the improved code `top` alignment does indeed respect the given height. The alignment still represents some issues, though: for some reason, `middle` puts the image even lower than `bottom`, and there's absolutely no difference between `baseline`, `sub` or `bottom`. It's possible that that depends on performance reasons for the text layout engine (like `middle`), but I'm just guessing.

Comment: @ekhumoro That said, I'm not able to track down *when* the change happened (somewhere between 5.7 and 5.13), which is something I'm still interested in. While I know that 5.7 is pretty old and I should not consider it that much, I'd still like to know *where* (and when/how) the change happened. In any case, I'll add an answer in the next days after further research. Thank you again.

Comment: Middle is partly relative to the x-height (which is typeface-specific), whereas bottom simply aligns to the lower edge of the line-box. Given that, it makes sense that it may be rendered lower. For sub and super, text is automatically rendered in a smaller font and aligned *within* the line-box, so it's not really surprising that images are treated differently. However, other than that, the overall behaviour is actually more consistent for images than text (i.e. compared with a modern browser). For images, it's only really sub that doesn't work properly (it should behave the same as bottom).

Comment: PS: I added a community wiki with some test output for comparison. The QLabel rendering has a few problems, but it doesn't seem way out of line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some test output for Firefox, Chrome and QLabel:

[image: screenshots]

AFAICS, the only obviously incorrect behaviour with QLabel is text/middle (which should align the text lower within the line-box) and image/sub (which should align the line-box the same as for bottom). The behaviour of the two browsers isn't *quite* identical - but I don't know which one is more correct.

HTML test page:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="font: 12pt dejavu sans">
<br>
<hr>
:: xX<span style="background-color: red">Text</span>Xx
 jyf xX<img src="red-small.png">Xx Default
<hr>
:: xX<span style="background-color: red; vertical-align: top">Text</span>Xx
 jyf xX<img style="vertical-align: top" src="red-small.png">Xx Top
<hr>
:: xX<span style="background-color: red; vertical-align: bottom">Text</span>Xx
 jyf xX<img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="red-small.png">Xx Bottom
<hr>
:: xX<span style="background-color: red; vertical-align: middle">Text</span>Xx
 jyf xX<img style="vertical-align: middle" src="red-small.png">Xx Middle
<hr>
:: xX<span style="background-color: red; vertical-align: sub">Text</span>Xx
 jyf xX<img style="vertical-align: sub" src="red-small.png">Xx Sub
<hr>
:: xX<span style="background-color: red; vertical-align: super">Text</span>Xx
 jyf xX<img style="vertical-align: super" src="red-small.png">Xx Super
<hr>
:: xX<span style="background-color: red; vertical-align: baseline">Text</span>Xx
 jyf xX<img style="vertical-align: baseline" src="red-small.png">Xx Baseline
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

*red-small.png*:
[image: red-small.png]